# In java, making a selective beep sound

Tags: java, applet, audio

I am trying to make several rectangles show up when the applet is started with a couple colors added in...I already have the beep audio file but from what i know, it will play throughout the whole program. Can someone please tell me how to make the beep sound occur only when the rectangles are clicked?

Comment: With some questions, one doesn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

There is some simple Audio API directly in Applet that you can use like this:

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet
{
    protected AudioClip beep;
    protected relativeBeepPath = "mybeep.wav";

    public void init()
    {
        //....
        try {
            beep = getAudioClip( new URL( getDocumentBase(), relativeBeepPath ) );
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void myRectangleWasClicked()
    {
        if( beep != null )
            beep.play();
    }
}
```